# set default reset button

Tags: reactjs, default, reset, use-state

reference code: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-usestate-in-react/

I'm trying to create a reset button that when clicked, the value resets to its default mode. How can I change the following code to do this?

```
    //App.tsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
function App(props) {
  const [count, setRandomCount, setDefaultNumber] = useState(
    function generateRandomInteger() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    }
  );
  function clickHandler(e) {
    setRandomCount(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "auto", width: 100, display: "block" }}>
      <h1> {count} </h1>

      <p>
        <button onClick={clickHandler}> Click </button>
        <button
          className="Set Default Number"
          onClick={() => setDefaultNumber()}
        >
          Reset
        </button>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

*Sorry if the formatting is off, thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way to do it,

reset number means, you need to set specific default one, something  like: `0,1,2`.

This code will help you out.

```js
function App(props) {
    const [count, setRandomCount] = useState(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))

    return (
        <div style={{ margin: "auto", width: 100, display: "block" }}>
            <h1> {count} </h1>
            <p>
                <button onClick={() => setRandomCount(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))}> Click </button>
                <button
                    className="Set Default Number"
                    onClick={() => setRandomCount(0)} //pass your default number
                >
                    Reset
                </button>
            </p>
        </div >
    );
}

export default App;
``
```

Answer (score 0):

Have initial defaultCount in variable and on Reset, update the count with default value.

```js
const defaultCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

function App() {
  const [count, setRandomCount] = React.useState(defaultCount);
  function clickHandler(e) {
    setRandomCount(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "auto", width: 100, display: "block" }}>
      <h1> {count} </h1>

      <p>
        <button onClick={clickHandler}> Click </button>
        <button
          className="Set Default Number"
          onClick={() => setRandomCount(defaultCount)}
        >
          Reset
        </button>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

useState() provides one stateful value and one function to update the value. In your case the stateful value is count, and the update function is setRandomCount. The next variable is meaningless.

To accomplish what I think you want to do, please try this instead:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(
function generateRandomInteger() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}
```

);

And now to assign some default value, add a helper function which uses setCount(). Same goes for assigning random count value. You can use setCount() as a wrapper for a random number generator.

Example:

```
function setDefaultNumber() {
  return setCount(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
}
```